# Change in Itachi's personality

Tags: naruto

[image][image]

How much and how did Itachi Uchihaa's personality change after the massacre?

Comment: His personality did not change at all. He is still the same person and still had the same goals. One of his missions was to kill the whole Uchiha clan. He did not want to, but he had to. After he killed almost all of them his brother was left. He didn't kill Sasuke because he loved him, so he just couldn't do it. Also if you compare him to Kakashi, than you can tell that Kakashi changed but Itachi didn't. Because Kakashi changed how he looked at life and Itachi looked at it the same way.